# Increment HTML value with jQuery on click / clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have this code:

```
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
              <div class="row" id="item1">  <!-- item -->

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">external_ref</label>
                  <input type="text" id="external_ref" name="item[0][external_ref]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo rand(1,9999); ?><?php echo strtr($date, array('-' => '', ' ' => '',':' =>'')); ?>">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">style</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][style]" class="form-control" value="mens">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">size</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][size]" class="form-control" value="large">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">color</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][color]" class="form-control" value="white">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">print_location</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][print_location]" class="form-control" value="front">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">quantity</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][quantity]" class="form-control" value="2">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">x_offset</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][print_x_offset]" class="form-control" value="10">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">y_offset</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][print_y_offset]" class="form-control" value="10">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">external_url</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][external_url]" class="form-control" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Sass_Logo_Color.svg/1280px-Sass_Logo_Color.svg.png">
                  <!-- // -->
                  <label for="one">external_thumbnail_url</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item[0][external_thumbnail_url]" class="form-control" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Sass_Logo_Color.svg/1280px-Sass_Logo_Color.svg.png">
                </div><!-- end right -->
              </div><!-- end item -->
              <div class="actions">
                  <span class="clone btn btn-default">Clone</span>
                  <span class="remove btn btn-danger">Remove</span>
              </div>
          </div>
```

And heres my jQuery (that i stole off of here)

```
<script>

var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

function clone(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
        .insertAfter(".clonedInput:last")
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'span.clone', clone)
        .on('click', 'span.remove', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("span.clone").on("click", clone);

$("span.remove").on("click", remove);

</script>
```

now, it clones fine, I can do that bit.

but what i need, is for every time the div is cloned

I need to change all of the "name" tags from item[0] to item[1]... item[2] and so on... so each clone has its own item number.

This is so I can send in jSON to my filemaker api.

Comment: What id is it getting instead?

Comment: Can't you just generate those later when creating the json based on the index?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myClones = $(".clonedInput");

for (var n = 0; n < myClones.length; n++) {
    myClones[n].setAttribute('name', 'clonedInput'+n);
}
```

Comment: That didnt work im afraid.
here's a fiddle of what ive got https://jsfiddle.net/5w0uwsxd/

Comment: and also, in the fiddle is a commented block of what the clone should do, changes item[0] to item[1] in the clone, and then it would be changed to item[2] on the next clone ect....